# How do I set the request timeout for dynamically loaded assembly (controller) in an ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I try to load assembly of controller type dynamically using below code.

```
var mvcBuilder = services
                .AddMvc(config =>
                    {
                        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .Build();
                        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                        config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                    })
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
                .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(m => m.FeatureProviders.Add(new RemoteControllerFeatureProvider(listOfPaths, Logger)))
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(op => { op.UseMemberCasing(); })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            
mvcBuilder.Services.AddSession(option => {
                option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
                option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

return mvcBuilder;
```

This line is responsible for loading the assembly dynamically:

```
.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(m => m.FeatureProviders.Add(new RemoteControllerFeatureProvider(listOfPaths, Logger)))
```

Class `RemoteControllerFeatureProvider` implements the `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` interface and `PopulateFeature()` method looks something like this:

```
public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
{
    string path = @"..\ClassLibProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ClassLibProject.dll";

    try
    {
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        var t = asm.GetTypes();

        foreach (var item in t)
        {
            if (item.BaseType == typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller))
            {
                feature.Controllers.Add(item.GetTypeInfo());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Debug($"Cannot load {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)}. {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Now this `ClassLibProject` is of type `Controller` and it throws 502.3 Bad Gateway error. Because there is an operation that takes more than 2 minutes (currently not focusing on optimizing that logic).

`ClassLibProject` is decorated with a filter attribute `[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(SessionPipeline))]`

Now the question is, is there any way to set request timeout to this `ClassLibProject` controller so that I don't get 502.3 Bad Gateway error.

Correct me if I am making any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the whole wrong direction. I just had to change requestTimeout parameter in web.config file of my API project. I did it and it worked smoothly.